# Finding Limit Using Taylor Expansion

Tags: calculus

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^4}$$

I want to use the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{R_n(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$

 So for I will use $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+R_4(x)$ and for $-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=-1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}-R`_4(x)$

So we get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+R_4(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}+R`_4(X)}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{12}x^4+R_4(x)+R'_4(x)}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{1}{12}x^4}{x^4}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{R_4(x)}{x^4}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{R`_4(x)}{x^4}=-\frac{1}{12}$$

But shouldn't $-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ be $-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=-1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}-R`_3(x)$ ?

If so what can I say about $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{R_{n-1}(x)}{(x-a)^n}$$?

Comment: "shouldn't $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ be $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=-1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}-R`_3(x)$ ?": no !

Comment: I suppose you mean $\cos x\color{red}-\mathrm e^{\color{red}-\tfrac{x^2}2}$ in the numerator. Otherwise there is no indeterminate form.

Comment: Sorry all it is minus (edited)

Comment: Does the remainder is $R'_4(x)$ because the expression is $-\frac{x^2}{2}$ as the polynomial has just 3 elements n=0,1,2

Comment: What do you mean exactly by $R_4(x)$ and $R'_4(x)$?

Comment: This can be solved easily by using L'Hospitals rule as well.

Comment: @Aretino just to differ between both remainders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index $4$ in $R_4$ refers to the remainder after three terms in Taylor's expansion. But the really important thing is the *order* of these remainders, not their name. Both are of order $6$, because the fourth term in both expansions is proportional to $x^6$. That allows you to say that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}R_4(x)/x^4=0$.

Comment: So the order of the remainder must be higher than $(x-a)^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, so you can discard the terms $R/(x-a)^n$ in the limit.

Comment: If I discard those terms what I get? What is R in the expression?

Comment: $R$ is the remainder: you did that yourself when you discarded $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{R_4(x)}{x^4}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{R`_4(x)}{x^4}$, because both tend to zero.